# Шаблон контейнера Joomla

Tags: javascript, php, css, joomla, joomla3

В мобильной версии сайта пропадает надпись поля. В обычный все хорошо. В чем может быть проблема?

На втором снимке видно какой код отвечает за выполнение.

/public_html/components/com_foxcontact/helpers/fieldsbuilder.php
Видим строчку       // Insert an empty option

```
$result .= '<option value=""></option>';
// Build a Textarea field

    private function BuildTextareaField($key, &$field)

    {

        $this->CreateStandardLabel($field);



        $result = '<div class="control-group' . $this->TextStyleByValidation($field) . '">' . PHP_EOL .

            $this->LabelHtmlCode . PHP_EOL .

            '<div class="controls">' .

            "<textarea " .

            'rows="5" ' .

            'cols="30" ' .

            'name="' . $field['PostName'] . '" ' .

            'title="' . $field['Name'] . '" ' .

            $this->JSCode .

            ">" .

            $this->FieldValue . // Inner Text

            "</textarea>" .

            $this->DescriptionByValidation($field) .

            '</div>' . PHP_EOL . // controls

            '</div>' . PHP_EOL . // control-group

            PHP_EOL;



        return $result;



    }
```

Для компьютера нет проблем, при открывании на мобильнике проблемы. Тех поля не пишется

Как сделать чтобы работало как и на полной версии?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

попробуй проверять в сафари, если мобильный на ios. Потому что сафари частично на всех браузерах на ios, даже в хроме.

Я думаю, что у тебя что-то не то с областями видимости, попробуй backface-visibility: hidden или translateZ(0) или translate3d(0,0,0).

Также ошибка может быть в том, что что-то ломается в php на мобилке (старое по, например). Советую зайти в браузерстек и поковыряться там. Там есть консоль, можно попробовать разные варианты.

Также лучше всего прикрепить ссылку, потому что не до конца понятно в чём именно проблема, это только предположения.

Comment: https://easy-moving.ca/piano-movers-toronto ссылка сайт. Я смотрю, что в браузере на компе все хорошо. Как мобильную версию включаю начинаются проблемы. Отличид JCP oprimaze  чтобы разобраться. Но что то не совсем все ровно понятно. Код нашел. Пустое меню ставиться. Текст нет

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Dr8JjvniMGeVa2
у тебя не запускается на мобилке плагин (или ты его специально отключаешь). В любом случае, у тебя на мобилке нативный селект, и это хорошо для производительности, так что я бы его оставила. А надпись можно сделать если внести в первый option нужный текст

Comment: Баг можно отловить в сафари, только задай нужный пользовательский агент http://joxi.ru/EA4yj9pupJ3P9r

Comment: Да вроде бы специально не отключал. Я на оборот хотел бы чтобы на мобильной версии они отображались как и на рабочем столе. А вот в если Я вношу текст в option первый и оставляю его не пустым. Тогда это работает везде и получается бардак. Первый должен быть всегда пустым. но иметь текст. Это для права выбора. Вроде как пустой и нужно выбрать, но тексте есть подсказка как на полной версии

Comment: [Полная версия](https://ibb.co/PC1CN63) [Телефон](https://ibb.co/zH9HMHH) **_СКРИНЫ_**

Comment: В сафари не работает

Comment: Еще вопрос открыт ребята

Comment: Забавно что за этот ответ +50...

Comment: @ДавидМанжула сама удивляюсь

Answer (score 2):

Я код страницы [easy-moving.ca/piano-movers-toronto](https://easy-moving.ca/piano-movers-toronto), которую вы указали.

У вас используется плагин типа [Select2](https://select2.org) (но скорее всего не именно он). Он скрывает нативную выпадашку и заменяет своей. В теории он позволяет добавлять поле поиска по пунктам если их много, или подгружать пункты через ajax. Так же он позволяет кастомизировать оформление выпадающего меню.

[image: код выпадающего меню]

Почему-то вы добавили пустой пункт в выпадашку. На мобильном клиенте (кстати, на Windows 10 на Google Chome с емуляцией моб устройства баг тоже присутствует) этот плагин не запускается и соответственно, первый пункт пустой. А надпись на выпадающем меню - это выбранный пункт. На ПК плагин работает нормально и он убирает пустой пункт.

---

Предлагаемые решения:

1. Отключить этот плагин вообще, а лейбл сделать над полем (кстати, ставить лейбл поля в самом поле - плохая практика, ведь после заполнения поля ее уже не видно и не понятно что это было за поле, особенно когда автозаполнения промазало).
2. Отключить плагин вообще и добавить подпись к выпадающему меню как указано [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5859221/5698975):

```html
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
  <option value="hurr">Durr</option>
</select>
```

3. Исправить плагин или заменить аналогичным.

---

#### Причина проблемы

Вооружившись дебаггерм, исследовал код страницы и нашел причину проблемы. На сайте используется плагин [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). Я посмотрел его код и обнаружил вот такой фрагмент:

[image: Скриншот кода Chosen]

Перед инициализацией плагина он проверяет, поддерживается ли браузер. А в функции проверки проверяется... не является ли он мобильным! Вот ссылка на место в исходном коде на GitHub: [abstract-chosen.coffee:367](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/91041bc9dd6867f9a1668050a1b092d92027f13b/coffee/lib/abstract-chosen.coffee#L367).

Что делать с этим - решайте сами. Можно изменить js-файл, убрав проверку; можно поменять библиотеку.

Comment: Если менять библиотеку то придется переписывать много. Странно что на мобильных версиях не работает корректно. Пустое поле делал как раз для того чтобы вставить вставить описание этого поля на мобильных версиях

Comment: Я воспользовался вашим советом. И сделал так.                              
`$placeholder = $this->Params->get("labelsdisplay") ? " " : $field['Name'];
$result .= '<option value="" disabled selected>' . $placeholder . '</option>';`  Но теперь появляется как на скриншоте отмеченный первое поля название. [_Скрин_](https://ibb.co/PxK6KD2) Стало как и хотел визуально [**стало**](https://ibb.co/yqGrdDh)

Comment: Да, это цена такого метода. Лично я думаю что это не критично

Comment: Другое решение - найдите js-файл и найдите регулярку, что на строке 925 и замените на строке 926 `false` на `true`. Но там код минифицирован, придется попарится немного. А еще у вас стоит какой-то плагин для оптимизации - после изминений нужно будет почистить его кеш. Думаю вы справитесь